# Add methods to class dynamically with types?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to make `def` type safe, without manually defining the interfaces?

```
// With proper `Cat.meow(message: string)` declaration on `Cat`?
const Cat = function() {}
def(Cat, {
  meow: function(message: string) { console.log('meow ' + message) },
})

const cat = new Cat()
cat.meow('I want food')

// Implementation
function def<T>(klass: T, fns: { [k: string]: any }) {
  for (let k in fns) {
    Object.defineProperty(klass.prototype, k, { value: fns[k],
      enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true
    })
  }
}
```

P.S. Maybe with some Babel AST transform magic for TypeScript?

Comment: No, this is not possible. But you could make it work for `const Cat = def(function() {}, { meow: … })`. Although really you should just write a `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's conceptually cleaner to just have `def()` return the desired constructor instead of trying to mutate the type of its `klass` argument.  Still, this *is* possible by making it an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that narrows the type of the `klass` argument to one which has an appropriate [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).

Possibly like this:

```
function def<A extends any[], T extends object, M extends Record<keyof M, Function>>(
    klass: (this: T, ...args: A) => void, fns: M & ThisType<T & M>
): asserts klass is typeof klass & (new (...args: A) => T & M) {
    for (let k in fns) {
        Object.defineProperty(klass.prototype, k, {
            value: fns[k],
            enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true
        })
    }
}
```

This accounts for `klass` having some argument list of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `A`, and tries to give a reasonably useful experience around use of `this` inside the `klass` and `fns` properties by using a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) on `klass` and [the magic `ThisType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) on `fns`. The idea is so that whatever `this` is in `klass` and whatever type `fns` is will be contextually available as `this` inside of the argument to `fns`.

So the following compiles and works as desired:

```
const Cat = function () { }
def(Cat, {
    meow(message: string) { console.log('meow ' + message) },
})
const cat = new Cat()
cat.meow('I want food') // meow I want food


const Dog = function (this: { name: string }, name: string) {
    this.name = name;
}
def(Dog, {
    bark() { console.log(this.name + " barks") }
})
const dog = new Dog("Fido");
console.log(dog.name); // Fido
dog.bark(); // Fido barks
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgCYFMQB4CCz0AeM6EqAzsgIYQCeA2gLoA0yAKvkSecggEYBW6WCwCyHYqQoAlIQgBOqLAGt0NBCGQiWAMUixEEAHyGAFMGQXkSgDaUyZAFzITMABZxHbFgDpflOQDmnjgAlMgAvIbIAG4IcKgsIBCeYgBkbO5krDQADuhY7OkihsAhTnZk6HIwFDYVyB7IMLno6la29sjpJhDoAO7Ovt7+QU6hEVGFmmEA3uaWIPLO1ugwVg0oSWSz85aWAPICQjDeGCBwvQAKcgh51TQmdfbeOTcwCM15LEosc3v-lmilGsYHQTi2dCUzF2AMsJDAAFsqpReCtwcDKiw+nI4DAUWimnJQSwoEhzgEwHJ8WDCaCYXsAL4hGEM4Cs4DAUnJNYAYUoa3CyHA0HgSGcs2QrLOJj5MF+MKRCD6JiR9koARpZBgOIgAQlXLICBW3msCACJgA5IqBhbkABqZCqsjq9BhBlMNnMg1rKD8iLIXoDWUmL387zWy0ASWQfWoa0WCFQFrCAHoU47WgNo7GIPGEImOZykFrkAARM3+4X6MUuTJOGYByhIpxanUBSUsCBNzXai565B-SxuDzeLtI-1j9AAbjZwGl5YC8r2vH8ShDA+QBqN6BNZtrI8n9uQACJkCu5EoyMe3Z6i9y0BXBYGy3vj9p4ghrzOt8bTebUGao7diEU7IGmyDvgBc6Aeea4gWB6aQQgZ6rmQQA)

Comment: The assertion function works in this toy example where the instance is constructed right after the `def()` call, but it does not work with `export const Cat = …`

Comment: You’d have to export a copy, just like all CFA effects (e.g, `const _Cat = …; def(_Cat, …); export const Cat = _Cat;`)

Comment: Unbelievable, you did it :)